# How to run multiple Integration tests at once in Redspot Ink!

Tags: ink, smart-contract

I am currently writing integration tests for my contracts using redspot, I can't seem to run all my integration tests at once, I can only run integration test by using the keyword `it.only`. Anytime I try running all tests, only the first test works fine and then i get this error when the next integration test tries to run.

```
     Error: the object {
  "error": {
    "message": "1010: Invalid Transaction: Inability to pay some fees , e.g. account balance too low"
  }
  "from": "5F2DEdhqyaDvPpasrhSLv8KxjdnVG1MZTAkHPA5doArnvQj4"
  "txHash": "0xd6f1a3d8fdf7bc94a162a5d777ccf91863dbc8a8bbfcad7ee343016423adbea8"
} was thrown, throw an Error :)
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you're emptying the account after the first test or the account is empty. How much funds does `5F2DEdhqyaDvPpasrhSLv8KxjdnVG1MZTAkHPA5doArnvQj4` have? Maybe you should send some more from `Alice` etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the setup, we resolved that via chatting in the [OpenBrush channel](https://matrix.to/#/!utTuYglskDvqRRMQta:matrix.org/$myo5nXGJVtMaJP6hBtdBWkcHR_BgBTfxXuDrv5UO8SQ?via=matrix.org&via=t2bot.io&via=matrix.parity.io).

The problem was that only Alice's account from Redspot has many tokens. Other accounts had only several units.